# When connecting to SQL Server 2005, SQL Server does not allow remote connections

Tags: sql-server-2005, .net-2.0

i only have MS SQL Server 2005. I use Dot Net framework 2.0. The error occured is like

> An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this website on [how to configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277).

Answer (score 0):

Go to  surface area configuration and select allow remote connection. Select both tcp and named pipes. Restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated that you *have* configured it to allow remote connections so follow these steps; http://www.linglom.com/2007/08/31/enable-remote-connection-to-sql-server-2005-express/

Answer (score 0):

Possible it is firewall problem try to switch it off. Also if you have named instance you should use change port in configuration manager.